# Instagram restrictions for Like permission

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, social-media-like

Since 4 days Instagram wants you to fill a form to get permission to any post action, like following someone through the Instagram API.

In the moment I am developing an Like App for Instagram (you like someones photo for coins, with whom you can buy likes on your picture after). Do you guys think its possible to get the permission from Instagram? Here are the new restrictions:

> The ability to POST and DELETE likes, follows and comments is restricted to applications that offer business services and not consumer facing apps. In particular, we may approve only the following types of business services:
>
> Media rights management: for example a platform for media publishers and brands to request permission from the Instagram Community to use Instagram content.
>
> Social media management: for example, a platform to help businesses integrate Instagram in their social media workflow.
>
> Use of these endpoints is also subject to the Instagram community guidelines. In particular, we do not tolerate any type of spam behavior:
>
> Automated actions
>
> Repetitive comments
>
> Self-promotion
>
> Commercial spam comments such as discount codes or URLs to websites
>
> Circumvention of intended Instagram functionalities

Do you think its possible to say that this is an App for Social media management? If not is there any other way to get arround it?

Answer (score 0):

They restricted to access follow and like. Before they restricted to access comments.

They grant access to Companies. And no free websites or services.

If that's the case I think instagram should remove api feature. Maybe we don't have to use instagram at all?